# One to zero...one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-model-builder

I can't seem to get the relationship between *Foo* and *Bar* right.

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}


public class Bar
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Name { get; set; }

    public int FooId { get; set; }

    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

With this structure I would normally have

```
public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
```

in Foo, but in this instance, that isn't a workable representation of my data.

You see....

*Foo* won't always have a *Bar*
...but...
*Bar* will always have a *Foo* and its FooId will always be unique across *Bar*.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // ...............

        modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
                    .HasOptional(cpi => cpi.Bar)
                    .WithRequired(api => api.Foo);

        // ...............
    }
}
```

I have tried multiple attempts at defining the relationship, but can't seem to get it right! I also could add a nullable BarId to Foo if that would enable me to do what I want (but I would prefer not to). *(see edit 1)*

I have googled it lots (and searched through, and tried), many stack overflow posts that were similar (but not the same).

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks

---

Edit 1 (in response to spenders comment):

These tables already exist in a number of live environments and are full of data so I would like to find a solution without editing the db table definitions... but if that is not possible I can add a column to achieve what I need.

Previously I had it defined as...

```
public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
```

... but that won't work for a piece of code I am writing using these tables.

---

Edit 2:

The above code gives the following error when I try and add a Bar.

"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Bar' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Identity insert is not turned off, I use it for all tables, except in this instance where EF seems to be turning it off based on my definition of these tables.

Comment: "I also could add a nullable BarId to Foo if that would enable me to do what I want (but I would prefer not to)" When the right answer is something that you would prefer not to do, you should provide a strong justification as to why this is not appropriate in your case. Why don't you want to do this?

Comment: Please see edit 1

Comment: So there must be a foreign key in your database schema that allows null?

Comment: Not at the minute. Up until now, it was ok to treat Foo/Bar as a one to many relationship. But I could add whatever is needed...

Comment: What is *not working*?  Your current code is exactly how EF expects a 1 to 0..1 relationship to be coded, including your `OnModelCreating()`.

Comment: Please see edit 2

Answer (score 0):

So your real problem is

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Bar' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

First off this error message means: *your are trying to insert a value into an identity column when it is currently configured to not allow that action (off)*.

Entity Framework is probably trying to insert zero because you have not told EF about the Identity Column; Which means you need to explicitly tell EF that your this column is generating your Ids from the database...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
                .HasOptional(cpi => cpi.Bar)
                .WithRequired(api => api.Foo);

    // needed
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>()
      .HasKey(b => b.Id)
      .Property(b => b.Id)
      .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
}
```

Comment: It was inserting using identity into that column perfectly correctly before I tried the one to one relationship version of the table definition. I wasn't defining it explicitly before.

Comment: I'm telling you how to solve this specific problem, if it worked before as some other relationship, that's fine, but this error message has a solution for this relationship.

Comment: I now get..... A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: Id

Comment: I dont understand why an annotation of Key didn't achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Shall we try with `DataAnnotations` ?

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string  Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}


public class Bar
{

    [Key, ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public override int Id {get;set;}

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My apologies, the tables ARE defined with key, but in making my Foo/Bar example, I didn't include those annotations.

Comment: Added them now, see above.

Comment: do you need `1:1` no ? why above my one is not working for you ?

Comment: Where is your FooId?

Comment: if you need `1:0:1` relationship then you don't need it.both tables have one `PK` value. `Foo` is a `principal` end. `Bar` is `dependant` end.try this.

Comment: I don't see where your FooId is. I need FooId for existing code!

Comment: no need.you cannot built a `1:0:1` relationship like that.that is by design.you have an error due to your mysterious `FooId`.try my post.

Comment: any feedback for this ? if it's not working please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Objects are nullable, so the relationship being optional doesn't require you to do anything different than your `.HasOptional()` declaration.

However, you're missing Foreign Keys with your relationships.

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Name { get; set; }

    public int BarId { get; set; } // Add this!

    [ForeignKey(nameof(BarId))] // Add this!
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Name { get; set; }

    public int FooId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FooId))] // Add this!
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```